# Error Archive for In-App Purchase … is invalid. The 'IAPProductidentifier' in the ContentInfo.plist must match

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

Hello I have this error when I try to upload content hosted by apple

[image]

Contentinfo.plist
[image]

ItunesConnect:
[image]

As you can see is the same and I can't upload it, its a sandbox tester BTW

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to input the whole product id ex: com.miguelDSP... etc

Comment: What was your solution for this problem? I am facing the same issue right now.